# Given some power series, how do I make one centered at a different point?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

Suppose I have a function defined as follows:

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(x-c_1)^n$$

How would I deduce the coefficients of the power series centered at a different point?

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n(x-c_2)^n$$

$$b_n=???$$

particularly without directly applying Taylor's theorem everywhere.

Comment: Write $c_1=c_2+\Delta$ (where $\Delta=c_1-c_2$) and run the calcs with binomial theorem. The new coefficients will be power series in $\Delta$, so you want $\lvert\Delta\rvert$ to be smaller than the radius of convergence of the original series.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli could you explain more as an example?

Comment: It is basically a convolution.

Comment: @copper.hat I'm not familiar with convolutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose without loss of generality that $c_1=0$ and let $r$ be the radius of $\sum_n a_n z^n$. Let us prove that for any $c_2$ such that $|c_2|<r$, the power series $$\sum_n \left(\sum_{k=n}^\infty a_k \binom kn c_2^{k-n} \right)(z-c_2)^n$$ has radius greater than $r-|c_2|$ and its sum equals $f$.

Consider some $z$ such that $|z-c_2|<r-|c_2|$. That implies $|z|<r$ in particular, so that 
$\begin{align}
f(z)=  \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k z^k 
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k (c_2 + z-c_2)^k\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{j=0}^k  a_k \binom kj c_2^{k-j} (z-c_2)^j
\end{align}$

Let $u_{k,j}=\left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
        a_k \binom kj c_2^{k-j} (z-c_2)^j & \mbox{if } j\leq k \\
        0 & \mbox{otherwise}
    \end{array}
\right.$

Let us prove that $(u_{k,j})$ is summable.

Indeed 
$$\begin{align}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{j=0}^\infty |u_{k,j}|
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{j=0}^k |u_{k,j}|\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{j=0}^k  \left| a_k \binom kj c_2^{k-j} (z-c_2)^j\right|\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty |a_k| (|c_2| + |z-c_2|)^k
\end{align}$$

The power series $\sum_n |a_n|z^n$ has same radius as the original one and, by choice of $z_2$, $|c_2| + |z-c_2|< r$, hence convergence of the last series.

Summability yields $$\begin{align}f(z) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{j=0}^\infty u_{k,j}
&=\sum_{j=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^\infty u_{k,j}\\
&= \sum_{j=0}^\infty \left(\sum_{k=j}^\infty a_k \binom kj c_2^{k-j} \right)(z-c_2)^j
\end{align}$$
as wanted.

Comment: Ah, thank you :D  I guess I could've figured that out with some ingenuitive thinking.

Comment: What happens when $|c_2|>r$?  Does it simply fail to converge or something weird like that?

Comment: It fails to converge, at least locally around $c_2$.

Comment: How does $|z-c_2| < r - |c_2|$ imply $|z|<r$? And how is $|z|<r$ used in the following equations?

Comment: @MusséRedi $|z|=|z-c_2+c_2|\leq |z-c_2|+|c_2|<r-|c_2|+|c_2|=r$

Comment: As to my second question, could you elaborate on the importance of the radius $r-|c_2|$?

Comment: Never mind, I see it is used to show that the new series has a radius of convergence less than $r$.

Comment: Shouldn't there be an inequality, as opposed to an equality, per the triangle inequality $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{j=0}^k  \left| a_k \binom kj c_2^{k-j} (z-c_2)^j\right|
= \sum_{k=0}^\infty |a_k| (|c_2| + |z-c_2|)^k$$?

Comment: @MusséRedi no,this is an equality, just use binomial theorem.